# Warning signs to look for in a potential customer?

Tags: project-planning

I have seen a few questions about how to interview potential employees and employers, but this is something fairly important that I've come across in the past and I'm sure a lot of other users here will have too:

If you are running a small development company, consultancy or working freelance, what are the warning signs you look for in a potential client? There must be some things that are indicators that a customer will require a lot of supervision, demand a lot of your time and perhaps need you to adjust your charging model accordingly- what are these in your experience and how do you handle them?

What are the red-flags that indicate to you that a customer is going to simply be too much trouble to work with at all? Where do you set the threshold for this decision?

Comment: This is a better fit for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), StackOverflow's sister-site.

Comment: I concur. I believe I asked it some time before Programmers existed.

Answer (score 4):

Look for how much detail they know about their project, and how much they want to talk about it. If they seem focused on the details, they may drive you crazy by trying to micro-manage your work. If they don't seem to know much about the details, then they (the customer) may be in over their heads as they don't know the scope of the project. A good customer will know the details when asked, but won't want to drone on about them excessively.

Oh, a quick way to make the customer choose their billing model: when explaining to them what your contract includes (working with them for requirements, development, testing, etc) add a note that this includes *x* hours of phone and e-mail communication, where x is some function of the size of the project based on experience. Add that additional time will cost $250 per hour in 30 minute increments. That will discourage them from contacting you for every trivial question, and to put together lists of things to talk to you, which makes contact more efficient. Assuming your value for x is reasonable, a low-maintenance customer will have no problem with it, so you can remove that clause from the contract, since it's irrelevant. A high maintenance customer will want to know why it's so little, what if it's just a teeny question, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Any of these:

- They don't have a clear idea of what they are trying to achieve
- They try to dictate a technical solution to you before you have even examined the requirements / They don't seem interested in your opinion as the consultant
- They agressively haggle over price
- If doing any kind of graphical front-end, they ask for spec-work in advance of any kind of agreement

Comment: +1, especially on the solution pre-requirements. But I disagree with the "no clear idea of what they're trying to achieve" ... all my clients come to me with vague ideas, half my job is to help them understand what they need.

And all of these can be solved by a solid client manager.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working as a contractor for a few years, and [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242996/dealbreakers-for-new-programming-jobs#243455) shows a few specific instances of reasons I've walked away from jobs.  What I want to see in a contract engagement:

- A strong business sponsor with
  genuine commitment to the project
  and the clout to remove obstacles.
- Evidence of adequate funding and
  support within the organisation for
  the project.
- A line manager who won't drop you in
  it or interfere in your work to
  cover their own arse.  This is a
  particular problem as you tend to be
  reporting directly to people on the
  first rung of the management ladder
  who don't really have much clout. 
  For this reason the first point
  about a strong business sponsor is
  quite important.
- Evidence that the project does not
  have powerful enemies within the
  organisation.

Edit:

- For the first point, asking who the
  businss sponsor is and where they
  live in the organisation is a good
  start.
- For the second point, ask for a
  reasonable market rate and if they
  quibble, it's a bit of a sign that
  someone's trying to do it on the
  cheap.
- For the third point, the line
  manager's approach is often apparent
  from the way the conduct interviews.
- For the fourth point, ask who might
  block the project and look for any
  hesitation in the response.

These are not hard and fast rules, but heuristics.

Comment: I strongly agree with the need for a strong business sponsor with a commitment to the project, but the evidence you're asking for can be difficult to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

We recently had an "experience" with a customer so straight off the bat:

1. Did you underbid? If so, it's quite likely that you wouldn't be able to meet the customer's expectations within your budget and profit margin constraints, and it's going to cause problems.
2. Other vendors' experiences. What experiences do other vendors have working with this customer? Also, are you replacing another vendor, if so, why? Could the same reasons apply for replacing you?
3. Are the requirements vague? (Of course they are) I mean do they keep changing all the time? were you forced to sign off the requirements in a hurry?
4. Do you have the backing and buy-in of the best people in your company to make this work? They may not be directly involved with working for this project but they should have some stake in making it work out with this customer.
5. New country? Cultural issues could kill you despite your best intentions. Think of having local partners or go betweens, if not an option, at least familiarize yourself with  the local language and customs.